# In C++ does returning a string created from a local char array cause a memory leak or undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am wondering if this would cause a memory leak or an undefined outcome in C++?

```
string foo()
{
    char tempArray[30];
    strcpy(tempArray, "This is a test");
    return string(tempArray);
}
```

I know this is a bad thing in C but I haven't found a definite answer for C++.

So everyone is saying no, but I am still confused as to when the memory is deallocated?

Lets say I have this method that calls the above method

```
void bar()
{
    string testString = foo();
}
```

At what point in the above code does the string object returned from foo() call its destructor? Is it immediately after getting copied into the object testString?

Comment: It would just seem incredibly unnecessary compared to the much more obvious `return "This is a test";`...

Comment: As an aside, your comments on answers here strongly give the impression that you think C++ is or resembles C -- it isn't. ;-]

Comment: Ya i know. Still trying to wrap my head around stuff.

Comment: Does this compile, or is it a typo: `string testString =  string foo();`?

Comment: It was a typo, its now fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens in your example is that the constructor with the signature

`string ( const char * s );`

is called. The constructor allocates new memory for a copy of the string and copies it to that new memory. The string object is then responsible for freeing its own memory when its destructor is called.

When you make a copy of a string, the [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) also allocates memory and makes a copy.

You should also take a look at the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) pattern. This is how `string`'s memory management works.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no memory leak, and you don't need to do all that, here is equivalent to your code

```
string foo()
{
 return "This is a test";
}
```

Comment: In your example you have a static string stored... In mine I have a temporary array, when it returns the pointer to the array would no longer contain the temp array just stack popped garbage

Comment: @BeenCoding2Long: No, your code does not return the temporary array, it copies its contents into a string. In both cases what's returned is a `string` object whose value is a copy of something else, but it makes no difference to the string object what it was a copy of.

Comment: Ah ok I see thanks! I have been coding in C so long it hard for me to get used to the object stuff.

Comment: You should be aware that there is an implicit constructor call in that code. The C string "This is a test" is implicitly converted to a `std::string` because the constructor isn't declared `explicit`.

Comment: @JørgenFogh: For what it's worth, `return string(tempArray);` also contains an implicit constructor call -- to the copy constructor of `string` in C++03, the move constructor in C++11.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Are you sure? I thought that it might be called but I was unsure about the exact semantics here, since we are returning the new object directly. The compiler is definitely not required to call the copy constructor and any half decent compiler will only emit one constructor call.

Comment: @JørgenFogh: yes, it's eligible for copy elision because it's an object (the return value) constructed by copying a temporary object of the same type (the expression in the return statement). Try it with a class that has no copy ctor (or private in C++03): `class F() { F(); }; F f() { return F(); }`. Result `error: F::F() is private`.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
char tempArray[30];
```

`tempArray` is a variable with automatic storage duration.  When `tempArray` "falls out of scope" it is automatically destroyed.  You copy the contents of this array (somewhat clumsily) in to a `std::string` and then return that `string` by value.  Then `tempArray` is destroyed.  It;s important to note here that `tempArray` **is the array**.  It is not a pointer to the first element of the array (as is commonly mis-perceived), but the array itself.  Since `tempArray` is destroyed, the array is destroyed.

There would be a leak if you used a variable with dynamic storage duration, such as with:

```
  char* tempArray = new char[30];
  strcpy(tempArray, "This is a test");
  return string(tempArray);
```

Note the `new[]` with no matching `delete[]`.  Here, `tempArray` is *still* a variable with automatic storage duration, but this time it is a pointer, and the thing that it points to has dynamic storage duration.  In other words, `tempArray` gets destroyed when it falls out of scope, but it's just a pointer.  The thing that it points to -- the `char` array itself, is not destroyed because you don't `delete[]` it.

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly efficient, but no, no leak.

Comment: Thanks.. Do you know why not? Where is the string stored if not in the registers of the return value?  And how is it cleaned up later?

Comment: It's stored by the string object, and is implementation dependent.  Most likely, it's on the heap, and it will be freed from the heap when the string variable goes out of scope.  In your case, when the caller of `foo()` goes out of its scope.

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't cause any leaks as you never allocate memory on the heap. If you used `malloc`, `calloc` or `new`.. and you never `free`/`delete` it. Then yes, memory leak!

The array is statically allocated, so it is created on the stack. `strcpy` doesn't return a dynamically allocated object, it fills the existing array, it knows how to do this because of the pointer you passed in - again, not allocated on the heap. A copy of the string object is made when you return the string.

Comment: Ah okay, so an entire string object is created and returned.  The same as if I returned a local structure and the object keeps track of how big the string is and where it is allocated?

Comment: A new string object is created and all the characters are copied into your that string object. But when you return that string, it returns another copy of the string object. That object knows its length and all that.

Answer (score 0):

You can always return local automatic variable from function by value. For any type this should be safe (unless copy constructor is not safe):

```
T foo()
{
   return T(...);
}
```

or:

```
T foo()
{
   T t
   return t;
}
```

Your example matches my first case.

What is not safe is returning pointer/reference to local automatic variable:

```
T& foo()
{
   T t
   return t;
}

T* foo()
{
   T t
   return &t;
}
```